# placeholder value for select not showing when using ngmodel

Tags: html, angular, select

I am trying to have a select drop down display the first option as a placeholder value

The following code works

```
<form (ngSubmit)="citySubmit(f)" #f="ngForm">
        <select>
          <option value="" disabled selected>Select Your City</option>
        <option *ngFor="let c of cities" [value]="c">{{c}}</option>
      </select>

      </form>
```

however the following code does not

```
<form (ngSubmit)="citySubmit(f)" #f="ngForm">
        <select
        [ngModel]="city">
          <option value="" disabled selected>Select Your City</option>
        <option *ngFor="let c of cities" [value]="c">{{c}}</option>
      </select>

      </form>
```

which leads me to believe I am using the ngmodel incorrectly.

Can I have some guidance please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be,

Change

**`From`**

```
 <select [ngModel]="city">
```

**`To`**

```
<select [(ngModel)]="city">
```

Comment: huh. I thought that would implement 2 way binding. Is that not a problem or am I wrong?

Comment: if you use ngModel its always two way binding